# How do I understand Transform properties in snap.svg?

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I have been trying to learn snap.svg and I have some doubts regarding the transform properties.  My question is pretty stupid but here it is

In the following sample code, what do the the numbers mean?

```
     {"transform" : "t-10 0 s0 32 32"}
     {"transform" : "r180 32 32"}
```

I am guessing that s stands for scale, Also what is the difference between animAfter and after? I am very new to SVGs.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The transform format is a string that is a sequence of transforms, so you can have several after each other.

**Edit: Snap doesn't make a distinction between upper/lower case these days, so this part does not make a difference (it maybe worth being aware of it though, in case you see some Raphael.js code and want to understand), the rest should still be relevant though...**

T/t = Translate (t is relative, T is absolute)
R/r = rotate(r is relative, R is absolute)
S/s = scale(s is relative, S is absolute)

Its worth looking at the [Raphael transform documentation](https://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/reference.html#Element.transform) if the Snap.svg doesn't have enough information, as there is a lot of overlap.

For transformations, some will reference a 'centre of origin' about which to rotate/scale etc, as sometimes you may want the centre of origin to be the object itself, sometimes 0,0, sometimes around a specific point.

`t-10 0 s0 32 32` would translate x,y -10,0 and then scale x,y,cx,cy so scale 0 on the x, 32 on the way around cx 32.

`r180 32 32` would rotate 180 degrees around point 32,32. You can normally use a comma or space to separate values.

after represents "attribute" values to set after the animation finishes. animafter represents "animation" values to set after the animation finishes.

Comment: Thanks Ian, this is the second time that you have helped me out regarding svg. :D

Comment: right, it looks like the translate is absolute regardless of CaSe.

Comment: if snap doesn't make a distinction between upper and lowercase, how would you translate in absolute coordinates then?

Comment: It performs an absolute translate normally. Do you mean how would you do a relative transform ?

Answer (score 4):

Snap seems to use the same syntax as [raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.transform). t is translate so thats translate -10 units in x. s is scale and r is rotate.

Comment: That's because both are written by [Dimitry Baranovskiy](https://twitter.com/DmitryBaranovsk), Snap is basically a modern take on Raphael which leverages a lot of the new modern browser features.