# Using Snap.svg to scale a polygon

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, jquery-animate, snap.svg

I have a polygon created below:

```
var s = Snap('#test');

var polygon = s.polyline(200, 286, 250, 200, 350, 200, 400, 286, 350, 373, 250, 373);

polygon.scale(2, 2);
```

How do I get the polygon to scale? I want it to grow to twice its size from the center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would apply a transform to it.

```
var polygon = s.polyline(200, 286, 250, 200, 350, 200, 400, 286, 350, 373, 250, 373);
polygon.transform('s2')
```

's' in this case is for scale (also t and r for translate and rotate). You can also give it an x,y amount of scale, as well as a center point to scale from. So you could do...

```
polygon.transform('s2,3,100,100')
```

To scale x by 2, y by 3 based on a center of 100,100 to scale from.

You can read this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20302801/how-do-i-understand-transform-properties-in-snap-svg) for further details on transform strings if desired.

Answer (score 1):

You could change Scale value by change `polygonScale` value.

> [Don't remove `viewBox` attribute](https://sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/)

https://jsfiddle.net/nsrrexdd/

```js
var s     = Snap('#test'),
 tl     = new TimelineMax(),
 polygonScale  = 2; // control

var polygon = s.polyline(200, 286, 250, 200, 350, 200, 400, 286, 350, 373, 250, 373);
polygon.attr({fill: 'red', class: 'myPolygon'});
// polygon.scale(2, 2);

tl.set(".myPolygon", {
 transformOrigin: 'center',
 scale: polygonScale
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.4.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<svg id="test" viewBox="0 0 500 500"></svg>
```