# Snap.svg animating position on 2d axis

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

Looking through the other posts about Snap.svg, I am not seeing much explanation regarding simple use of the animate function.

I can't quite understand the documentation and current examples of using 
`element.animate`.

I see that there are specific things that can be done (transform, rotate).. but what if I would like to just move something on a simple 2D axis?

Here is my current code snippet:

```
var s = Snap("#elevBox");
var elev1 = s.select("#elev1");
if(toggleColor == 0){
    elev1.animate({
        //transform: 'translate(-30,100)',
        transform: "r5,200,200",
        fill: "lightgreen"
    }, 1000);
    toggleColor = 1;
}else {
    elev1.animate({
        //transform: 'translate(0,0)',
        transform: "r5,100,100",
        fill: "red"
    }, 1000);
    toggleColor = 0;
}
```

I have `toggleColor` linked to clicking a button so I toggle between the two conditions in the `if-else` statement.

Can someone please advise me on how I can modify the attributes in transform to move left -> right or up -> down?

If there is any more information that would be helpful for me to provide, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Using `transform: 'translate(...)` does not work? I tried it and I see no problem moving objects around.

Comment: @ConnorsFan It's not that it doesn't work. I just wasn't getting the exact results I wanted from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To control translate: `transform: 't300,300'` Scale: `transform: 's2'` Rotation: `transform: 'r45'`
You could make all in single statment: `transform: 's2r45,300,300'`

You could select any element by `Snap("#elevBox");` 
**Useful references:**

> Thanks [Ian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1429053/ian): [How do I understand Transform properties in snap.svg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20302801/how-do-i-understand-transform-properties-in-snap-svg/20305995#20305995)
>
> http://svg.dabbles.info/
>
> http://codepen.io/collection/xnrJc/

```js
var s = Snap("#elevBox");
var toggleColor = 0;


function start() {
 s.animate({
        transform: 't100,100',
        fill: "lightgreen"
    }, 1000, end);
}

function end() {
  s.animate({
        transform: 't300,300',
        fill: "red"
 }, 1000, start);
 } 


 start();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.4.1/snap.svg.js"></script>
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
 <rect id="elevBox" x="100" y="100" width="100" height="100"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks very much Sohaib! This post helped me achieve what I needed. I was able to animate my SVG object in the way I wanted by using 'translate'.