# Snap.Matrix().scale(...) does not work as expected explained in Snap docs

Tags: snap.svg

I try to learn the use of Snap.SVG. Creating an new Snap matrix I get unexspected results with the method matrix.scale(). Using el.transform("s...") will work as described in the Snap docs. Here the only used script code:

```
var s = Snap(#svgout);
var box = s.rect(100,70, 100,60).attr({opacity: 0.3});
var box2 = box.clone().attr({fill: "#0f0", opacity: 0.5});
var myMatrix = new Snap.matrix();
myMatrix.scale(0.5);
box2.transform(myMatrix);   // isn't using the center of box2
```

With myMatrix.scale(0.5,150,100) the coordinates of the centre of box2 it doesn't scale. I have to use myMatrix.scale(0.5,0.5,150,100) with both horizontal and vertical scale factors and the coordinates of elements centre for the expected result.
The shown results are the same in Firefox, Opera and Chrome. I'm using the newest Snap.Svg library and with the previus one it's the same result.

I hope to get some help, Yours faithfully, D. Mietke

complementary to Ian's answer I have an element box2 and myMatrix for scaleing the element. The Snap docs tell me in

```
Matrix.scale(x,[y],[cx],[cy]);
```

that the parameters in [] are optional and the only use of x will scale horizontal and vertical with the same factor around the centre.

```
box2.transform("s0.5");   // works fine
box2.transform("s0.5,150,100"); // same result (150,100) is the centre
```

in the first line the methode transform("...") doesn't know about the middle of box2 so as myMatrix. In the second line the transform string works with one scale faktor for horz. and vert. but in myMatrix I have to write

```
myMatrix.scale(0.5,0.5,150,100); // both scale factors for one
```

applied to box2 and obtained the matrix with

```
var m = box2.transform().localMatrix; // matrix(0.5,0,0,0.5,75,50)

myMatrix.scale(0.5,150,100);  // doesn't work
```

applied to box2 the var m will show matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)

```
myMatrix.scale(0.5);  // doesn't use the centre like the transform("...")
```

applied to box2 the var m will show matrix(0.5,0,0,0.5,0,0)

A few days ago all worked fine (yes!) with the same result by the use of 
box2.transform("s0.5"); or box2.transform(myMatrix); with predefined matrix as in the examples above. Two days later and up to now the results are unexpected. I don't see what I misunderstand in the use of myMatrix.

With kind regards, D. Mietke

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a couple of things. Firstly in the docs, the optional form of Matrix.scale takes 4 args, scalex, scaley, centerx, centery. So it seems reasonable to just duplicate scalex into scaley if they will both be the same.

For the code question of why the matrix isn't scaling around the objects center, it's because there is no way for a matrix to know what the objects center is (as there is no element associated!). And an SVG scale will scale around 0,0 still.

So the difference is, the transform strings are there to make life easier, and take all of that stuff into account if wanted.

But if you do these two lines...

```
var myMatrix = new Snap.matrix();
myMatrix.scale(0.5);
```

There is no object associated to know what it should scale around, so it will just do an SVG matrix scale from 0,0. (I believe the docs are wrong when it says "Default cx, cy is the middle point of the element."  as there is no element involved with this currently).

When you later do

```
box2.transform(myMatrix);
```

It will just apply that matrix, nothing more.

So really if you want the easier route, use transform strings. Thats what they are there for. You very rarely need to use those matrix commands with Snap, so if you are doing, it could be that you are making life more difficult for yourself.

```
box2.transform('s2');
```

As this form of transform is applied to the element (as applied to a matrix), it knows where the center is, so it can be more helpful and add the center for you.

You can find further info on the transform strings [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20302801/how-do-i-understand-transform-properties-in-snap-svg)

Comment: sorry, but problem usolved. I extended my observations. Please can you have a look at it?

Comment: Have you updated to Snap 0.5, as there was a bug in there that could have affected some work, if so, I would update to 0.51 or revert back. I think this line is wrong in the docs "Default cx, cy is the middle point of the element." as there is no way for the matrix to know which element is referring to. AS mentioned don't use the 3 parameter version of Matrix.scale, use the 4 parameter version. I would put a minimal test highlighting any error on a jsfiddle.

Comment: Actual I have Snap.SVG 0.5.1 and the parameters y, cx, cy are shown with [ ] to be optional, but not so by Matrix.rotate(a, x, y) with x,y as the centre. I try to learn SnapSVG and was confused and couldn't find a logical explanation. Many thanks for your help an time.

Comment: In the docs it doesn't say that x,y is optional on rotate, only on scale, and it doesn't imply you can just use 3 of them. I think I wouldn't trust them for the matrix methods either way. I would personally still stick to transform strings though. I've never had to use the Snap matrix command in a couple of years using it, and always used transform strings.